# Setup Azure SQL Managed Instance to connect to on premise server on a VPN

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, paas

I have SSIS packages on my Azure SQL MI server that needs to have access to files on a server. The server needed to be accessed is on a VPN. Is it possible to add the MI to the VPN, so it can access the files on the server? Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

The Managed Instance doesn't run your SSIS packages in Azure, it simply hosts them in a SSIS Catalog DB.  Azure Data factory SSIS runtime will execute the packages.  Therefore, you need to connect your Azure Data factory back to the on premises network to access the remote server. This can be done using an integration runtime proxy or you can join the SSIS integration runtime to a virtual network.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/join-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-virtual-network